# how to use keycondition in Query method from DynamoDb Table using boto3

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

'
I am trying to query the Dynamodb table to display the items from the table.

I am using a table.query with some conditions such as projectionexpression etc.

Since we knew that scan Method scans the whole table which is time-consuming, so im trying to use a query where i am getting an issue with putting **key conditions** as it is mandatory criteria.

So can you help me in this code.
using this URL :http://localhost:0000/rsi/hotels

My Repository.py ->

```
  def list_items(self):
        ProjectionExpression = "Id,#Name,Description"
        ean = {"#Name": "Name"}
       # Using this URL: http://localhost:0000/rsi/hotels
       # how can I use keycondition for this in below table 
        esk = Key('Id').gt(0)   # stuck here dono what exact condition to 
         give 
        limit = settings.AWS_SCAN_LIMIT
        items =  []      
        tableResponse = table.query(
            ProjectionExpression=ProjectionExpression,
            ExpressionAttributeNames=ean,
            KeyConditionExpression = esk,
            Limit=limit           )

        items.extend(tableResponse['Items'])

        while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in tableResponse:
            tableResponse = table.query(
                ProjectionExpression=ProjectionExpression,
                ExpressionAttributeNames=ean,
                ExclusiveStartKey=tableResponse['LastEvaluatedKey'],
                KeyConditionExpression=esk,
                Limit = limit
                )
            items.extend(tableResponse['Items'])

         return items
```

ERROR:  ERROR - An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported

Actually, my table consists of

```
 id   name  description
 1     hai    des
 09    bye     des2
 123   there      des3

 etc......
```

So, i am not able to get of any other option on how to use parallel scan and query effectively, So,i have approached you, people.

Please help me on this!

Comment: @Users //users can you pls help me on this query

Comment: First of all, there's no way for other people to run code on **your** localhost! Second, always give meaningful names to your variables. `ean`, `esk` will only make it difficult for anyone to understand what you're trying to do... Third, provide necessary information. For example: what are you trying to query: by name, id, description? Explain your use case... Also, what is the partition and sort keys in your table?

Comment: @RenatoByrro, Thanks for your reply.
I want to get all the items from the table .since the scan is taking a lot of time and memory, I am trying to use query method.
Here, id is partition key and there is no sort key.

Comment: In order to get every item Dynamo will need to read every item, no matter if you use Scan or Query. Using a Query improves performance because Dynamo can use indexes to get to a specific subset of your database without having to read everything and then filtering. Since you want everything, it's gonna need to read everything anyway...

Comment: What you could do is use a query with a limit of X items per query. Then you repeat the query using the LastEvaluatedKey to continue from the last item and get X more, until you covered the entire database. You could set a time interval between queries (say 1 or 2 seconds), in order to keep resource consumption low at any point in time. See this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html#Pagination

Comment: @RenatoByrro, Thanks for your help , it helps me really